# Sum Totals of a various sections is not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a loop to select a particular header in a sheet and sumtotal the numbers below the header. The header is available under different categories so the loop runs through to find the header- The Sumtotal is not working fine from the second loop.

```
Sub LoopText()
    Dim rFirst As Range, r As Range
    Dim A As Range
    Dim Sumtotal As Variant
    
    Sheets("FA_CP_Report").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Set A = Range("F:G")
   Do
      If rFirst Is Nothing Then
         Set rFirst = A.Find(What:="Sub-ledger")
         Set r = rFirst
      Else
         Set r = A.Find(What:="Sub-ledger", After:=r)
         If r.Address = rFirst.Address Then Exit Do
      End If
         r.Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Do
            Sumtotal = Sumtotal + ActiveCell
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Sumtotal
        
   Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: your code does not make a sum? It's just selecting the last cell in the header col (Selection.End(xlDown).Select), checks if the next cell is blank and then paste this value in the next row. On the second iteration the "after:=r" always exits, even if their is a second header to catch. I will have a look but with an alternative approach.

Comment: "not working fine" is an insufficient description of the problem for anyone to be confident of solving it. Better to describe exactly what you *want*  and then what you *actually get* instead.

Comment: Actually issue is we have "FA_CP_Report" sheet where is contains "Sub-ledger" header in three different categories. I created a loop to search the header but was not able to sumtotal the numbers under each "Sub-ledger" header. During the first search of header we are able to get the sumtotal but when it goes to second and third search the Sumtotal is incorrect.

Comment: Why do you program something yourself if Excel has a feature to do this for you? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a

Comment: We have to do this for multiple workbooks. So creating an macro would do them in seconds for all the workbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement isn't totally clear, but this variation assumes that for each occurrence of "Sub-ledger" in columns "F" and "G" there follows in the cell below a set of numbers, and that what you want is to add a subtotal of those numbers at the bottom of the continuous set of values.

```
Sub LoopText()
    Dim rFirst As Range, r As Range
    Dim rTot As Range, rVal As Range
    Dim SearchIn As Range
    Dim SLtotal As Variant
    Dim GLtotal As Variant
    
    Sheets("FA_CP_Report").Select
    Set SearchIn = Range("F:F")
    Do
        If rFirst Is Nothing Then
            Set rFirst = SearchIn.Find(What:="Sub-ledger")
            If rFirst Is Nothing Then Exit Do '===>
            Set r = rFirst
        Else
            Set r = SearchIn.Find(What:="Sub-ledger", After:=r)
            If r.Address = rFirst.Address Then Exit Do '===>
        End If
        Set rTot = Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.End(xlDown)) ' Setup zone to sum
        SLtotal = 0
        GLtotal = 0
        For Each rVal In rTot
            SLtotal = SLtotal + rVal.Value
            GLtotal = GLtotal + rVal.Offset(1, 0).Value
        Next rVal
        r.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0).Value = SLtotal ' Add subtotals
        r.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 1).Value = GLtotal '
    Loop

End Sub
```

EDIT: Updated to match example

Comment: My Requirement : There are 3 "Sub-ledger" header in G column under three categories. We want to sumtotal the values below each header and show the total sum. The code provided only totals the first Sub-ledger header. The other two Sub-Ledger totals are incorrect totals.

Comment: Thank you. but it didn't provided the result i required.

Comment: You example makes the requirement clearer; this was not how I read your description, and I didn't see anything in your code suggesting that there was a parallel GL subtotal required. I added a row's gap to the subtotal as your layout suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Sub LoopText()
    Dim arr, sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FA_CP_Report")
    arr = sh.Range("G1:G" & sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 'load source
    
    Dim j As Long, subsum As Long, count As Boolean
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If VarType(arr(j, 1)) = 8 Then
            count = True
        ElseIf count = True And arr(j, 1) <> "" Then
            subsum = subsum + arr(j, 1)
        Else
            sh.Cells(j + 1, 7) = subsum
            count = False
            j = j + 2
            subsum = 0
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Or in a multi col version:

```
Sub LoopTextMulti()
    Dim arr, sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FA_CP_Report")
    arr = sh.Range("G1:H" & sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 'load source
    
    Dim j As Long, i As Long, subsum As Long, count, startCl As Long
    startCl = 6
    ReDim count(1 To UBound(arr, 2))
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            If VarType(arr(j, i)) = 8 Then
                count(i) = 1
            ElseIf count(i) <> Empty Then
                If arr(j, i) <> "" Then
                    count(i) = count(i) + arr(j, i)
                Else
                    sh.Cells(j + 1, startCl + i) = count(i) - 1
                    count(i) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ceci, Thank you for your code. This code didn't worked out. It is just passing through the cells but the result was not provided.

Comment: what do you mean? the sum will be printed 2 rows under the last row of the respective col. ("Sub-ledger" in row 1)

Comment: arr = Sheets("FA_CP_Report").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2 is getting an error.

Comment: which error? I also edited the code as I think I misunderstood your objective. you want to count the number of occurrences of the header, not sum the numbers under the header right? And the "header" can be anywhere in the col?

Comment: There are 3 "Sub-ledger" header in G column. We want to sumtotal the values below each header and show the total sum. The code provided only totals the first Sub-ledger. The other two Sub-Ledger totals are blank.

Comment: I'm confused, you want to "sum values" or "count occurences"? The updated code doesn't sum, it's counting. can you provide a sample of your data structure? assuming you have blank rows in your source the ".currentregion" will indeed not give the expected result.

Comment: I have added the snapshot for your reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232788/discussion-between-sathish-thirunavukkarasu-and-ceci).